# Html [object Object] in Angular Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, pipe

I have a todo that takes as inputs:

todo.ts:

```
import { TodoTag } from "./todo-tag-custom";

export class Todo {
  ...
  tags: TodoTag[];
}
```

todo.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let todo of todosFiltered()">
<td>{{todo.tags | json}}</td>
```

where the tags are of type: string. When I try to display it in my Html using `{{ todo.tags }}`, it gives me `[object Object]`. Additionally, when I use a pipe to convert to json using the html code above, I get:

```
[ { "id": 1, "tags": "Hello World", "todoID": 1 }, { "id": 2, "tags": "Not my 
tag", "todoID": 1 } ]
```

How can I change the {{  }} to just give me the string from the todo.tags when I iterate through my list of todos?

For reference, todosFiltered() returns the following:

```
todosFiltered(): Todo[] {
    if (this.filter === 'all') {
      return this.todos;
    } else if (this.filter === 'active') {
      return this.todos.filter(todo => !todo.done);
    } else if (this.filter === 'done') {
      return this.todos.filter(todo => todo.done);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `tags` is an array, you'll need something to iterate through it.

```
<tr *ngFor="let todo of todosFiltered()">
    <td>
        <span *ngFor="let tag of todo.tags">{{ tag.tags }}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here `tag` will be just one entry of the array of tags, for instance

```
{ "id": 1, "tags": "Hello World", "todoID": 1 }
```

Comment: Not sure that that worked. The span you provided returned the following elements:

    <!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object" 
    }-->

Comment: Based on the code you provided, that should work. How does the data `todosFiltered()` returns look like? Can you `console.log(todosFiltered())` somewhere in your code and show me what it looks like?

Comment: It looks like this:
todosFiltered(): TodoCustom[] {
    if (this.filter === 'all') {
      return this.todos;
    } else if (this.filter === 'active') {
      return this.todos.filter(todo => !todo.done);
    } else if (this.filter === 'done') {
      return this.todos.filter(todo => todo.done);
    }
 Where should I put the console.log(todosFiltered())? (I'm fairly new and have never used it before...) (See edited code above)

Comment: My confusion comes from `export class Todo {
  ...
  tags: TodoTag[];
}` and then "where the tags are of type: string". You say `tags` is string, but the code you provided has it as an array in class Todo. So if `todosFiltered` is returning multiple `Todo`s, then `tags` is an array. So you have to further iterate on tags with an `*ngFor` and then get the "tags" property on Todo.tags to get the string.

Comment: So your todosFiltered method returns an array of Todos, which from your code looks like: `[ { tags: [ { "id": 1, "tags": "Hello World", "todoID": 1 } ] } ]`, so you see how there are 2 arrays? Then you need 2 `*ngFor`s